# Why does adding a time trend can make an explanatory variable more significant in time series data?

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance, trend

So the statement is:

> Adding a time trend can make an explanatory variable more significant if the dependent and independent variables have different kinds of trends, but movement in the independent variable about its trend line causes movement in the dependent variable away from its trend line.

I don't really understand the meaning. Why can variable signifcance increase?

Comment: Did you quote any source? In that case, please cite!

Comment: @User1865345 I find this one https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/3-adding-time-trend-make-explanatory-variable-significant-dependent-independent-variables--q31624057 which, unfortunately, provides very little other background, references, or context.

Comment: Hm, I see @AdamO. A proper citation would have in a cogent way provided a context which might be missing in this narrow passage. It's a good precedent, in general, to always cite your source.

Comment: The source is : Jeffrey M. Wooldridge, Introductory Econometrics a Modern Approach - 7e. Page 355.

Answer (score 0):

If I could pick apart the quoted text: "different kinds of trends" is not well defined.

If we define "different kinds of trends" as $E[Y_{0,t}] \ne E[Y_{1,t}]$ for two repeatedly sampled time series, $Y_0$ and $Y_1$, at any time point $t$, then you can still test the grand hypothesis whether $\mathcal{H}_0: E[Y_0] = E[Y_1]$ using methods for independent data if the design is well balanced. That is, a plain old t-test won't hurt you. However, the choice to model the time trend can increase the power of this analysis.

Consider this simulated design

```
n <- 100
nt <- 4
nx <- 2

df <- expand.grid(id=1:n, t=1:nt, x=1:nx)


df$y <- with(df, 0 + 4*rnorm(nt)[t] + 1*x + rnorm(ncol(df)))


par(mfrow=c(2,1))
boxplot(y ~ x:t, data=df, at=c(0,1, 3,4, 6,7,9,10))

boxplot(y ~ x, data=df)
```

Here's a picture to explain:

[image]

Here time functions as a "blocking" factor using classic experimental design language. Even though we have defined time to be entirely random and unrelated to treatment, you can see that in groups stratified by the times 1 through 4, the observable difference between groups is far more noticeable than in the crude or aggregate scenario. This corresponds to more precise inference in ANOVA or linear regression using $p$-values:

In my simulation, the Type 3 SS test statistic for inference on the $x$ factor without adjustment for $t$ is 4 and after factor adjustment for time, it increases to 31.

Answer (score 0):

The full quote is :

> In some cases, adding a time trend can make a key explanatory variable more significant. This
> can happen if the dependent and independent variables have different kinds of trends (say, one upward
> and one downward), but movement in the independent variable about its trend line causes movement
> in the dependent variable away from its trend line.

I did ***not*** fully follow. However I would like to share my incomplete understanding.

What is this conversation all about ? It is about ***spurious regression***.
What is ***spurious regression*** ? It results from a kind of ***omitted variable bias*** where the ***time trend*** is the omitted variable.

Now, when we omit variables correlated with one of the explanatory variables the coefficient of the explanatory variable may be biased ***upwards*** or ***downwards***. In simple examples the bias is ***upwards*** ie on including the time trend the explanatory variable becomes ***less*** significant. The author is trying to describe a case where the explanatory variable becomes ***more*** significant on adding a time trend. That is the key point.

I think, the author is trying to say that time affects the dependent and independent variable in opposite ways. One positive and one negative.

Further, the independent variable ***x*** moves about its trend. When it moves about its  trend it may cause the dependent variable ***y*** to move ***more*** or ***less*** about it's trend.

Let's us consider the case when ***y*** moves ***more*** about it's trend. I think this is what the author means when he says

> movement in the independent variable about its trend line causes movement in the dependent variable away from its trend line.

Notice: in this case when x goes from below its  trend to above it's trend it will induce ***positive*** correlation between y and x.

So there is ***positive*** correlation between y and x (due to movement of x around it's trend) and then there is a ***negative*** correlation between y and x due to the time trend.

When I control for the time variable, x will have a +ve coefficient.

When I ignore the time variable, the common negative correlation due to the omitted variable bias will cause the coefficient of x to be ***less positive***.

In other words: on adding a time trend the coefficient of the explanatory variable will become ***more significant***.

PS: I am not 100% certain of this.